# How to tell when an HTML textarea has been changed by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, jquery-events

A widget I'm using modifies an HTML textarea element.  I need to know when that element has been modified and preferably I'd like to actually hide that element as well.  I'm using jQuery, so I naturally tried the `$('#textarea_id').change()` event.  But it's never triggered because I guess the textarea never loses focus.

What's the best way to monitor that textarea, preferably hidden (CSS has `display:none`)?  Please don't tell me `setInterval`...

Comment: There may be some non cross browser solutions

Comment: Not really an answer, but I'd suggest seeing if the widget has its own `change` event.

Comment: What's wrong with `setInterval`? It's the obvious solution here.

Comment: I have no access to the widget code other than to link to it in my <script src="...

Comment: What's wrong with setInterval is that it's asynchronous which requires me to do a lot more work in my UI to deal with that... and it's just ugly :).  Of course if there's no other option...

Comment: You could trigger the change when you modify the textarea: $('#txt').trigger('change');

Answer (score 1):

You could manage this with a global variable.

```
var text = "";

$('#textarea_id').bind("keyup paste", function(e){
    if ($(this).val() != text)
    {
        // text changed
        text = $(this).val();
    }    
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/n8keN/

Comment: seeing if the value is different is not the issue, it's monitoring when the value has changed and "keyup paste" doesn't work when other javascript code modifies the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.keyup()`. If you don't want the event to fire every keypress, have it restart a half second timer every keypress and have the timer trigger the things you want to happen when the user stops typing.  You can play with the time to get it to your liking.

Comment: "keyup" doesn't work when other javascript code modifies the textarea.